# Moving SRC from Index.html to Component ui5

Tags: sapui5

So I have the following line in my Index and my app works perfectly.

```
<script src="/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/project/util/moment.js"> </script>
<script src="/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/project/util/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.js"> </script>
```

But now my application is being called as a Component I need to move this to the Component section. But I'm unsure how to do this. I've tried a few things with no luck.

If I remove this line of code I get the same error in my application when its ran as a standalone as I do when I call it via the component, so I know this is the line of code that is missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please tell us what those two scripts in your index.html are ment to do?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to include an external js library.

1. Include in the UI5 controller where you use the library.

   ```
   sap.ui.define([     "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
   "<projectNameSpace>/<realtivePathofJSLibrarytoTheComponent>/moment.js"
   ], function(Controller){
   .... Use momnet() here....
   }
   ```

   2. Include in the Component.js, as in 1. By this "moment" will be available through the app. Though the next option is preferred.
   3. Mention in the manifest.json in your application (in manifest.json --> sap.ui5 --> resources). This option also allows
      you to use "moment" throughout your app.

   "sap.ui5": {
           "resources": {
             "js": [{
                  "uri": "/moment.js"
              }]
    } }

Answer (score 1):

Use better the "resources" node in your manifest.json files like this:

```
    "resources": {
        "js": [ {
            "uri": "URI/to/JS/file.js",
            "name": "filename.js",
            "version": "1.1.1"
        }]
    }
```

Or use JQuery.sap.require() in your init event in the Component.js file

```
  jQuery.sap.require('namespace.folder.fileName')
```

There are two good posts you should read:

1. https://blogs.sap.com/2017/04/30/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-modules-in-sapui5/
2. https://blogs.sap.com/2016/10/29/sapui5-application-startup-performance-best-practices/